# Is the lag from modern wireless mice higher than wired ones?

Tags: lag, wireless-mouse

I have a wired mouse that I would like to replace with a wireless mouse. Currently my options are Logitech M310 and HP X3500 because of the full size and of the price.

I play from time to time with first person shooting games and I wonder how the lag will affect the play.

Are newer mice such as the ones listed so slow to affect non-professional gaming? While a "gamer" will care about every millisecond, I think that any total lag below  15 ms (one frame at 60 Hz) will be fine.

I searched online but I couldn't find scientific measurement of said input lag.

Comment: For the most part you cannot feel the difference in lag time between wired and wireless mice... just annoying sometimes when the battery gets low the mouse will work intermittently. Also make sure that the wireless receiver is close the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends greatly on the mice being compared.

Logitech with the G502 Lightspeed, [is allegedly faster than many wired mice](https://www.logitechg.com/en-ca/innovation/lightspeed.html).

As for in general, in theory, wireless would take longer due to having to convert digital signals into radio, and radio back into digital. However in practice, this time can be extremely short if done well.

Given your requirement of <15ms, I think any wireless mouse would work for you, as beating that is very common for wireless mice, especially gaming oriented ones that know how to cater to their target demographic.

Comment: I bought a Cherry MW 2310 2.0 and I tested my reaction time with https://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime. I see no difference, therefore I guess the wireless mouse adds no lag (or no more than 5 ms, completely irrelevant in my case).